# iOS: Timer animation on separate thread

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a simple animation to make a label look like its counting upwards, which I put in a timer.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector:@selector(animateScore:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The animate score selector increments the labels text until it gets to the desired integer then invalidates the timer.

Right now, it stalls while other UI stuff is going such as reloading table view sections.

I tried running this code, but it didn't work:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:weakSelf selector:@selector(animateScore:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

      [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
     });
```

Comment: The `animateScore:` method should be running in background, and not the allocation of the `NSTimer`

Comment: When you use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` you don't need to (and shouldn't) `addTimer` to the runloop...

Comment: You cannot update the UI this fast anyway, even in OpenGL code the fastest screen repaints possible are 60 FPS. Your timer is running at 1/100 of a second, it is a waste of resources, slow the timer down and just create it once. There is no value in using GCD for this, it is just a UI update that needs to happen in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is using a special timer class CADisplayLink, which fires every time the device's screen is updated. Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // …
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkDidFire:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    // …
}

-(void)displayLinkDidFire:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
    // Update label text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` already adds the timer to the current run loop (which may not be the main run loop since you execute this on a background queue).
Use `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` instead. This creates the timer but does not add it to the current run loop.